# env -i and bash-c

Tags: environment-variables

Can someone please help me understand the difference between

```
bash -c 'echo $SHELL $HOME $USER'
```

and

```
env -i bash -c 'echo $SHELL $HOME $USER'
```

I tried going over it many times but I still don't get it. I'm studying about `env` and `bash -c` appears in the example. What does `bash -c` do exactly?

Comment: `bash -c 'commands'` runs the commands, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

`env -i` executes the specified command with an empty environment.

`bash -c …` executes the argument of the `-c` option (the `…`) as a bash code snippet.

`bash -c 'echo $SHELL $HOME $USER'` is equivalent to `echo $SHELL $HOME $USER`, because running bash doesn't modify these variables (at least as long as they're initially set).

`env -i bash -c 'echo $SHELL $HOME $USER'` runs `bash` with the arguments `-c` and `echo $SHELL $HOME $USER`, and with an empty environment. When bash starts, it sets some shell variables, including `SHELL` (which is only set as a shell variable, not exported in the environment of any child program that bash might start). Thus, when bash parses and expands the command `echo $SHELL $HOME $USER`, the variables `HOME` and `USER` are unset but `SHELL` is set to `/bin/sh` (I don't know why bash does this), and this command displays `/bin/sh` followed by two spaces.

The single quotes around the argument of `bash -c` ensure that the text within the quotes is not expanded by the shell from which you run `env -i bash -c '…'`, so that text is passed as-is to the bash subprocess.

Comment: "SHELL is set to /bin/sh (I don't know why bash does this)"


This is because, on some unix systems at least, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`. This is very much dependant on which system you're running though, Debian and Ubuntu for instance `/bin/sh` links to `/bin/dash`

Comment: @Robo No, that doesn't explain it. How do you go from “bash is sometimes installed as `/bin/sh`” to “bash sets `SHELL` to the user's login shell but does not set `HOME` to the user's home directory or `USER` to the user's name”?

Comment: Ah sorry, answering the wrong question

when you run `bash`, by default it won't act as though it was invoked from a login shell. You can emulate this by passing the `-l` flag

    `[root@5f992ef6d2b6 /]# env -i bash -lc 'echo $SHELL $HOME $USER'
    /bin/bash root`

But `$HOME` is still not being set, because this is set by the `login` process before bash is launched. Bash relies on the `$HOME` variable for a bunch of things, but never actually sets it


    `If (SHELL) it is not set when the shell starts, bash assigns to it the full pathname of the current user's  login shell.`